# SQL - Passing a variable that stores the where clause

Tags: sql, variables, amazon-redshift, where-clause

I am trying build a SQL query that passes a variable that stores the where clause. I inturn, plan to call this variable in the SQL query.

Given below is what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @temp int(20)
SET @temp  = '''select emp_id from employees'''
```

SQL query where I use call the variable:

```
select emp.emp_id
      ,emp.name
      ,team.team_name 
from employees emp 
join team team on emp.team_id=team.id and emp.id in (@temp)
```

On trying the above I keep getting the syntax is wrong, could anyone guide me where am I going wrong in the above code. Thanks.

Comment: [`IN` does not work that way](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html#IN). The normal solution is a table-valued parameter, but to do what you're  doing here, you'd need dynamic SQL. If you really want dynamic search conditions (the current example you've got is not a good one) make some time available to read [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Sever`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: you must sort out the correct tag for your dbms - is it mysql or redshift?

Answer (score 1):

You get a list back of Ids there so holding that in a standard int variable will not work. Also you can not do IN like that

Something like this would work

Create a user defined type table

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntList] AS TABLE(
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Insert your employers ids in the user defined type table

```
DECLARE @EmpIDs IntList;
INSERT INTO @EmpIDs SELECT emp_id FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Now do a select on that table in your IN clause

```
SELECT emp.emp_id
      ,emp.name
      ,t.team_name 
FROM EMPLOYEES AS emp 
JOIN TEAM AS t on emp.team_id=t.id 
and emp.id in (Select Id FROM @EmpIDs)
```